# NopCommerce 3.80 - Dashboard chart weekdays language

Tags: nopcommerce

Is it possible to change the language (to Portuguese) of the weekdays presented in the dashboard charts?

[image]

NopCommerce v3.80

Answer (score 1):

Those labels come from the server, more precisely from the `date = searchWeekDateUser.Date.ToString("d dddd"),` line inside the `LoadOrderStatistics` method in `Nop.Admin.Controllers.OrderController` class (line 4260)

The easy way to fix this should be to change the locale at application level for the admin area but there is an [open issue](https://github.com/nopSolutions/nopCommerce/issues/30) about that solution

There are other alternatives such as:

1. **Change the source code** line to take the "pt" locale, recompile and redeploy
   `date = searchWeekDateUser.Date.ToString("d dddd",new CultureInfo("pt")),`
2. **Create and register a new global `ActionFilter`**, you can set the culture there just for the controller and action you need:

   ```
   public class Culture : ActionFilterAttribute
   {
       private string _actionName;
       private string _controllerName;
       private string _culture;

       public Culture(string culture)
       {
           _culture = culture;
       }

       public Culture(string culture,string controllerName,string actionName)
       {
           _culture = culture;
           _controllerName = controllerName;
           _actionName = actionName;

       }

       public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
       {                
           if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(_culture) &&
               (_controllerName == null || filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName.Equals(_controllerName)) &&
               (_actionName == null || filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName.Equals(_actionName)))

           {
               System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(_culture);
               System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(_culture);
           }
       }
   }
   ```